# Are E-Cigarettes as unhealthy as conventional cigarettes?

Tags: environmental-health, smoking, cigarettes

At my community college, a person in a booth was handing out pamphlets talking about the health problems with cigarettes and e-cigarettes. The pamphlet seemed to indicate that e-cigarettes could be as unhealthy as conventional cigarettes. When I asked the person handing out the pamphlet whether we just had insufficient research to conclude that e-cigarettes were safer or whether there was research indicating that e-cigarettes were unsafe, she clarified that it was the latter.

This brings me to my question:

**Is this person right? Do we have evidence that E-Cigarettes are as unhealthy as conventional cigarettes?**

EDIT:

As this question has now been marked as a duplicate, and the duplicate question has been linked to, I should note that my question was primarily answered by the response to the other question that wasn't selected as the answer, via this quote:

> But what the FDA report does not address at all is a comparison between the long term health effects of smoking vs. vaping, for the very simple reason that there isn't any data on that. So if by "better" you mean "has fewer long term health effects" the answer is "insufficient data."

Comment: Yes, and the answer that wasn't selected as an answer actually answers my question. I didn't see that question because my question contained 'e-cigarette' instead of 'electronic cigarette', which is what the other question referred to. You can close this question.